# How can I export to CSV with condition?

Tags: json, csv, select, export-to-csv, jq

```
cat target.json | jq '.[] | select(.sex | endswith("female")) |@csv'
```

I tried the code above to output csv with the condition, in which only girls are listed.

"target.json"

```
[ 
 { 
  "name": "Mike", 
  "age": "15",
  "sex": "male"
 }, 
 { 
  "name": "Dan", 
  "age": "10",
  "sex": "male" 
 }, 
 { 
  "name": "Kasia", 
  "age": "5",
  "sex": "female" 
 }
]
```

However it fails to create and says this error code.

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): object ({"sex":"...) cannot be csv-formatted, only array
```

Can anyone show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following makes no assumptions about the ordering of keys within objects.  It also produces a CSV header line, and ensures the output conforms with the typical CSV requirement that the result be "rectangular":

```
jq -r '
  (.[0]|keys_unsorted) as $keys
  | $keys,
    (.[] 
     | select(.sex | endswith("female")) 
     | [.[ $keys[] ]])
  | @csv 
' target.json
```

Comment: Thanks! I got this error back though jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
  (.[0]|keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, (.[] | select(.sex | endswith(“female”))| [.[ $keys[] ]]) | @csv

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -r '
  .[] 
  | select(.sex | endswith("female")) 
  | to_entries
  | map(.value) 
  | @csv 
' target.json
```

to_entries to:

```
[
  {
    "key": "name",
    "value": "Kasia"
  },
  {
    "key": "age",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "key": "sex",
    "value": "female"
  }
]
```

and map(.value) to:

```
[
  "Kasia",
  "5",
  "female"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for beautiful answer! Indeed it shows the csv formated data on Terminal. But it looks like it doesn't export *****.csv file

Comment: I could do that by adding > ***.csv in the end of it. Could you show me how to export without any condition if I want to export all of the data to csv file?

Comment: try: cat target.json | jq -r '.[] | to_entries| map(.value) | @csv ' > out.csv

Comment: WARNING: This solution assumes the ordering of the keys within the objects is consistent.

Comment: I got this error jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | to_entries | map(.value) | @csv                                       
jq: 1 compile error